# How do I stop the fadeOut from triggering if menu is already open, using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm unsure why my code triggers the fadeOut() effect if the menu is already open? See code below:

```
$('.rtmenu').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });

$('.rtmenu').mouseout(function(){ 
     $(document).one('click',function() { $('.rtmenu').fadeOut(200); }); 
 })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have should work provided it's located inside a `document.ready` and the `.rtmenu` elements aren't being created dynamically.  [You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4eZrP/).

If they're created dynamically, change it up a bit using a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler and [`.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/), like this:

```
$('.rtmenu').live('click', function(e) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); });
$(document).click(function() { $('.rtmenu').fadeOut(200); });​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4eZrP/1/)

Comment: @Nick, Thanks for your help, although your code makes the menu just fadeOut once clicked...is there a way of only having this happen when the DIV('.rtmenu') is showing? Thanks

Comment: @Nasir - Only visible things can fade out, it'll ignore it otherwise...can you explain a bit more?  I'm not quite following, the code posted should only fade out a `.rtmenu` if it's shown...what's different about behavior are you're after? That would help me see what you're wanting a bit better.

Comment: @Nick - my orignial code works fine only up to the first time I click & DIV(.rtmenu) fades out. After this if I click the main menu links to display DIV(.rtmenu) it(.rtmenu) appears then fades away instantly. I think it has something to do with $(document).one(... part. I need the fadeOut to only happen if the DIV(.rtmenu) is visible. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: @Nick - I have looked into bind() and each() ...my apologies I'm a complete novice at JavaScript & JQuery

Comment: I think I found a solution, just had to change 'click' to 'mousedown'...see here:  $('.rtmenu').live('click', function(e) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); });
 $(document).mousedown(function() { 
   $('.rtmenu').fadeOut(200);
 });

Comment: @Nasir - Is there some other code acting on these elements that's not in the question?